# Trying to figure out how to prevent mice/grass from getting in garage

Tags: garage, pest-control

Going to post a picture as I won't be able to explain this very well. Basically, the wood and weatherstripping on garage doesn't go all the way to the ground. I am trying to figure out the best way to close this off to keep grass from weed wacker, bugs, and mice out of the garage.

I tried Xcluder - Garage Door Rodent Shield, but it is very flimsy and not wide enough and won't completely cover the gap. Also, it won't prevent grass from getting blown into the garage.

Here is a picture:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Moth balls (will remind you of your grandmas house) and/or ultrasonic pest deterrents if  you have power there.  Don't get the cheap ones, they don't work well. That and get some materials that you can use to fill the gaps.

Comment: Have you tried a cat, it will get rid of the mice but not the grass! If you can see light mice will probably get through. With the fall coming they will be trying to stay warm. You could feed them by placing peanut butter in a trap. There are weed killers that will kill the grass and keep it out for maybe a year or so. I do not know what is allowed in your area.